# Private npm registry with fallback to global registry

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts, npmrc

Installing the npm package from the global registry( **https://registry.npmjs.com** ), if that package does not exist, install it from Azure Artifacts.
To do this:

First I create **.npmrc** in the root directory where the **package.json** file is.

```
registry=http://server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/registry/
//https://registry.npmjs.com/

always-auth=true

; begin auth token
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/registry/:username=DefaultCollection
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/registry/:_password=[XXXXXXX==]
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/:username=DefaultCollection
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/:_password=[XXXXXXX==]
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token
```

**NOTE: We have to replace XXXXXXX  with token.**

I run the following command to install the **express package**

```
npm install express
```

What I expect is : It has to install the **express package** from the global registry

When run the following command

```
npm install cac-common
```

I expect to install package above from Azure Artifacts(this is my private pakcage.)

But It does not work. where I'm wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is one possible solution.

If you set your company/organization packages to have a scope like `@mycompany`. You can define an `.npmrc` like this

```
@mycompany:registry=http://server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/registry/
//https://registry.npmjs.com/

always-auth=true

; begin auth token
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/registry/:username=DefaultCollection
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/registry/:_password=[XXXXXXX==]
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/:username=DefaultCollection
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/:_password=[XXXXXXX==]
//server/DefaultCollection/CMP/_packaging/Frontend-Feed/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token
```

That way, when you install `@mycompany/mypackage`; npm will get it from Azure and the rest from the public npm registry.

I hope that works for you...

Comment: this didnt work...npm still tries to install all other packages from @mycompany registry.

Comment: Weird!! That's what's been working for us in the project. Are you getting particular error ?